# How to print filename with rget from Perl using Net::FTP::Recursive;?

Tags: perl

I'd like to print the filename or the complete remote path

```
use Net::FTP::Recursive;
$ftp = Net::FTP::Recursive->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0);
$ftp->login("anonymous",'me@here.there');
$ftp->rget( '/dev','' );
$ftp->quit;
```

Comment: Documented at http://p3rl.org/Net::FTP::Recursive#rget-ParseSub-yoursub-FlattenTree-1-RemoveRemoteFiles-1- - what are you having trouble with, specifically? As your post is written, it expresses a desire, not a question.

Comment: I have found this script https://metacpan.org/source/JDLEE/Net-FTP-Recursive-2.04/samples/rget

Answer (score 0):

Try this to list the filenames:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP::Recursive;

my $ftp = Net::FTP::Recursive->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0);
$ftp->login("anonymous",'me@here.there');
$ftp->cwd('/dev');
print join("\n", $ftp->ls());
$ftp->quit;
```